# Strict mode causes right-floating image to work differently on IE8 than left-floating

Tags: html

I've seen posts about strict mode changing image padding, but I've got a different problem.  I'm trying to get text to float around images.  This works in FF 11 (well there's a small change in vertical position, but it doesn't bother me).  But in IE8, left-float works and right-float only works for one paragraph.  I made a minimal test file, and the problem went away.  Eventually I figured out that putting a strict DOCTYPE was what caused the problem to reappear.  (And yes, I need that DOCTYPE to get my code to pass the W3C validator.)

I had prepared images of how it looks, but I'm not allowed to post images yet.

The left-floating image always comes out like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  first paragraph 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX second paragraph
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I want the right-floating image to come out as a mirror image of that, and that's what I get in FF 11 and IE 8 without a DOCTYPE.

> ```
>                                first paragraph  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
>                                                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>                               second paragraph  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
>                                                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> ```

But when I put in the DOCTYPE, IE8 changes that to

> ```
>                                first paragraph  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
>                                                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>                                                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
>                                                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>                                               second paragraph
> ```

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN'
      'http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
      xmlns:v='http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#'
      xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'
      xmlns:og='http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/'>
  <head>
    <title>float test - strict</title>
    <style>
      img { margin: 0 10px; }
      img.fl { float:left; }
      img.fr { float:right; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p dir='rtl'>
      <img class='fr' src='http://www.htmlgoodies.com/images/blue.gif'
       height='100' alt='img'/>
      first paragraph
    </p>
    <p dir='rtl'>
      second paragraph
    </p>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <p dir='ltr'>
      <img class='fl' src='http://www.htmlgoodies.com/images/blue.gif'
       height='100' alt='img'/>
      first paragraph
    </p>
    <p dir='ltr'>
      second paragraph
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure is wrong...

This is a better way...

http://jsfiddle.net/VH7QC/1/

Comment: Thanks, much better now.  
  
But there's still a difference between the left and right versions on IE8 but not on FF11,  The left version wraps below the bottom of the paragraph, but the right one only does this on FF, not IE.  See [link]http://jsfiddle.net/VH7QC/2/[/link], all I changed was longer text in the second paragraphs.

Comment: I decided to check it on IE Netrenderer http://netrenderer.com, IE9 and IE8 do the same thing (wrap at the bottom of the left, not on the right), IE7 wraps on both sides, IE6 and 5.5 wrap on neither side.

Comment: Use css reset...  Eric Meyer Reset CSS http://www.cssblog.es/10-tecnicas-para-resetear-css/